# Show alertDialog with radiobuttons when click a listViewItem

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner, android-alertdialog, onitemclicklistener

I have a listView with 2 items in it, the 2 items are "seconds" and "minutes"
When I press "seconds" I'd like a alertDialogBox to open en show 5,10,15,... seconds. Same when I press minutes

Something like this:

[image]

But I'm having trouble implementing it, because I don't understand very well how it is working. Here is the code I have:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingsList);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        String[] values = new String[] { "Seconds", "Minutes" };

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                AlertDialogView();
            }
        });

    }

    private void AlertDialogView() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "15 secs", "30 secs", "1 min", "2 mins" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowDialog.this);//ERROR ShowDialog cannot be resolved to a type
        builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog with ListView and Radio button");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(ShowDialog.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(ShowDialog.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is clearly explanatory, you are missing a `semicolon`. Your code should be like

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
        {
           AlertDialogView();
        }//ERROR I'm GETTING HERE is Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
     };
```

and the above code should be inside the `onCreate()`. In the code that you provided, its floating in the middle of nowhere!

Comment: I changed the code, how stupid of me... But I'm still getting the error on the showDialogBox. How come? The error is `ShowDialog cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: It would be better if you'd post the logcat so we can see what you're talking about

Comment: Not possible, I can't compile because I'm having errors. Logcat is empty

Comment: Instead of ShowDialog.this it should be the context. There is no such thing called as ShowDialog. It should be SettingsActivity.this instead.